# how to write tag and value to image EXIF

Tags: r, exif, exiftool

I have an unorganised collection of images taken in the field over several years. They could be a valuable asset and reference, if only it were more convenient to find them and some descriptors of the subject.

All of the images have GPS coordinates in the EXIF. That data enables grouping by geographic region.

In order to enable further grouping of the collection, I would like to add keys and values, eg ProjectName and LC_BMRG_002 plus Subject and one of landscape, vegetation, people (etc).

In order to build a Shiny application, I began building the necessary functions separately from the interface.

Using the excellent exifr package took me rapidly forward on the spatial side, but on adding keys and values I am stuck.

I adapted the example from exiftool.org. Having copied an image into the working directory, I tried to write a new value to an existing key. In this case the top line is the given example and the second my working. Clarity is an EXIF key in these images.

`# exiftool -Comment='This is a new comment' dst.jpg`

`exiftool -Clarity='Childers' AAA_9083.JPG`

which returns

`Error: unexpected symbol in "exiftool -Clarity='Childers' AAA_9083.JPG"`.

On investigation, I found that the keys vary with some being num and some char. This explains why Clarity would not accept the string Childers.
None the less my success was no better with an existing char key and changing its value.

My current strategy is to add a key or two and the values.

`exiftool -district+='Childers' AAA_9083.JPG`

returns

`Error: unexpected '=' in "exiftool -district+="`

Minor edits like removing the = sign did not help. I checked that the file was owned by the RStudio user.

Has anyone some advice about writing keys to EXIF, using R and exiftool?

Comment: Are you on Windows? I think it generally gets unhappy with single quotes... maybe try double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the thought, Mark. I am using my Ubuntu linux server in this project.

Comment: Is this on the command line or through some other interface.  The `Error: unexpected '=' ` is not an exiftool error.  It looks more like you are passing `exiftool -district+=` as a single parameter, resulting in an attempt to run all of that, spaces included, as the name of a program.  Under exiftool, the resulting error should be `Warning: Tag 'district' is not defined`, as there is not a tag with the name `District`.

Comment: Hi StarGeek
You have almost certainly identified the problem. This command is sent from a .R file. I test in the RStudio console.
For my example exiftool -district+='Childers' AAA_9083.JPG, my intent was to add the key 'district' to image AAA_9083.JPG and attach the value Childers. 
Could you please assist me to
1./ add a tag named district to each image in the current folder and a default value to it
2./ update the district tag for a specific image with a specific value.
From there I should have a better foundation for automating some tasks eg updating a key for a vector of images

Comment: The problem is, there isn't a tag called "District".  At least, none that exiftool knows about.  From the command line, run the command in [exiftool FAQ #3](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q3) on a file that already has this "district" filled out to see if you can find the actual name of the tag you want to write.